# How to add custom keyboard shortcuts to GWT CellTable

Tags: java, gwt, keyboard-shortcuts, celltable

I created a CellTable in GWT and I set
`.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.ENABLED);`
to enable the use of keyboad.

Now I can move up and down with keyboard and press spacebar to interact with each row. Is it possible to add custom keyboard shortcuts to this CellTable? For example, I want to change the spacebar to act as the enter button.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch any key pressed and do whatever you like. If you override a default behavior of that key, you need to cancel the native event first, then do your actions.

```
CellTable<Object> myTable = new CellTable<Object>();
// build myTable

myTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Object> event) {
        if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) {
            // Get selected object or objects from your SelectionModel
            // Do something with this object or objects, or
            // do something with the selected row or rows
        }
    }

});
```

Be careful with the spacebar. It acts as "page down" in some browsers, so users may not expect your custom behavior when pressing it.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand can give me a example? in my code i have a addSelectionChangeHandler where i add the method addCellPreviewHandler

Comment: You add this CellPreviewHandler directly to your CellTable widget. Your SelectionChangeHandler is added to your SelectionModel - it should be used to get selected object(s). You don't need to add CellPreviewHandler to your SelectionChangeHandler unless you are trying to modify selection behavior (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

1- You should not disable keyboardSelectionPolicy first.

2- You should add this block to constructor or onLoad method:

```
myTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<GuiltyAccusationInfoDto>() {
@Override
public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<GuiltyAccusationInfoDto> event) {
    if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_UP || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN
            || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_RIGHT
            || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_PAGEUP || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_PAGEDOWN) {
        selectionModel.setSelected(listOfData.get(table.getKeyboardSelectedRow()), true);
    }
}});
```